# Callback URL not approved by Twitter

Tags: twitter, oauth-2.0, spring-social, spring-social-twitter

My application built upon [spring-social-twitter](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.social/spring-social-twitter) that enables users to sign in with Twitter has stopped working recently.

I've got an error message as below:

> Callback URL not approved for this client application. Approved callback URLs can be adjusted in your application settings

Note: I'm using Spring Social Twitter version 1.1.2.RELEASE. And if you use Spring Social Twitter version 1.1.0.RELEASE, you might get a slightly different error message as below:

> POST request for "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token" resulted in 403 (Forbidden); invoking error handler

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Twitter recently (in May 2018) enforced that sign-in-with-Twitter users must whitelist callback URLs for security reasons (see [the announcement](https://twittercommunity.com/t/action-required-sign-in-with-twitter-users-must-whitelist-callback-urls/105342)).

This means callback URLs have to be explicitly and identically set up for all supported third-party applications. You can setup the callback URLs in your Twitter's application setup page: https://apps.twitter.com

For example, if your callback URL is `http://localhost:8080/myApp/signin/twitter`, you must add it to the list of Callback URLs in your Twitter's application setup page exactly as it is: `http://localhost:8080/myApp/signin/twitter`

[image]

See also [the documentation on Twitter callback URLs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/callback_url.html).

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with this since Twitter made the changes to increase security. My android app would use a callback URL and the same URL in the Intent Filter.  But since the change, the URL I was using had to be registered in the Twitter developer portal.  I was using ouath://myapp, but Twitter does not accept that as a valid URL (website).

After a bit of digging, I found that for apps you can specify any scheme but only as a scheme. For example I used myapp:// as the callback URL.

In my app, my callback URL was myapp://whatever, and in the Intent filter, I used :

```
<data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="whatever">
```

Twitter accepted the callback URL and it correctly redirected back to my app after the user authenticated with their Twitter credentials.

I has originally used just a normal website, and that worked too, but after validation by Twitter, it asked if I wanted to redirect to My App, or to a Chrome browser. Using the above approach it will simply return to your app.

**After I did all this, I realized that I could have just added Oauth:// as a call back URL and my app would have worked without change.**

Comment: what you wrote in **BOLD** is what helped me. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me too! Twitter's documentation contains a misleading example: `You want to use example://authorize as your callback URL`, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by adding those callback URLs to Twitter's whitelist.

`twitterkit-{Twitter API Key}://` for iOS.

`twittersdk://` for Android.
[image]